# How do I get Terraform to throw a specific error message depending on what account the user is in?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a terraform module that does domain delegation. For several variables there is some validation  against a hard-coded value to check that a user is using valid inputs, for example:

```
resource "null_resource" "validate_region" {
  count = contains(local.regions, var.region) == true ? 0 : "Please provide a valid AWS region. E.g. (us-west-2)"
}
```

with `local.regions` being hard-coded and `var.region` being a user-set variable. The above code works in that when a user sets the variable wrong, it throws an error like this:

```
Error: Incorrect value type

  on .terraform/foo/main.tf line 46, in resource "null_resource" "validate_region":
  46:   count = contains(local.regions, var.region) == true ? 0 : "Please provide a valid AWS region. E.g. (us-west-2)"

Invalid expression value: a number is required.
```

I now need to validate that the AWS account the user is currently using is the correct one. In this case it's up to the user to set the account id of the correct account in their variables, and my code needs to pull the account id of the account that's running the module and compare it against the user's variable. I've tried something like this:

```
data "aws_caller_identity" "account" {}

resource "null_resource" "validate_account" {
  count = data.aws_caller_identity.account.account_id == var.primary_account_id ? 0 : "Please check that you are using the AWS creds for the primary account for this domain."
}

data "aws_route53_zone" "primary" {
  name = local.primary_name
}
```

with various syntax changes on the `"{data.aws_caller_identity.account.account_id == var.primary_account_id}" ? 0` part in an effort to get the logic to work, but no luck. I would like it to throw an error like the region validation does, where it will show the error message I wrote. Instead(depending on syntax), it will work as expected for the correct account and throw a `Error: no matching Route53Zone found` error for the incorrect account, OR it will throw a completely different error presumably because the syntax is screwing things up.

How do I get this to work? is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out that this block:

```
data "aws_route53_zone" "primary" {
  name = local.primary_name
}
```

was running before the account validation resource block. Add in a `depends_on` like so:

```
data "aws_route53_zone" "primary" {
  name       = local.primary_name
  depends_on = [null_resource.validate_account,
  ]
}
```

And it's all good.

Answer (score 9):

What I do is create an if statement in the locals block and source a file with the error message I want to display.

```
variable "stage" {
   type = string
   desciption = "The stage to run the deployment in"
}
locals {
   stage_validation = var.stage == "prod" || var.stage == "dev" 
        ? var.stage 
        : file("[Error] this module should only be ran for stages ['prod' or 'dev' ]")
}
```

The output of setting the stage variable to anything other than 'dev' or 'prod' is as bellow

```
╷
│ Error: Invalid function argument
│ 
│   on main.tf line 10, in locals:
│   10:     stage_validation = var.stage == "prod" || var.stage == "dev" 
│           ? var.stage 
│           : file("[Error] this module should only be ran for stages ['prod' or 'dev' ]")
│ 
│ Invalid value for "path" parameter: no file exists at This module should only be run for stages ['prod' or 'dev']; this function works only
│ with files that are distributed as part of the configuration source code, so if this file will be created by a resource in this
│ configuration you must instead obtain this result from an attribute of that resource.
╵
```

This is helpful because it allows you to write an error message that will be shown to the person trying to run the code.

Answer (score 6):

Terraform as of 1.5.0 now has a "check" block you can use to check arbitrary conditions. For example:

```
check "health_check" {
  data "http" "terraform_io" {
    url = "https://www.terraform.io"
  }

  assert {
    condition = data.http.terraform_io.status_code == 200
    error_message = "${data.http.terraform_io.url} returned an unhealthy status code"
  }
}
```

https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/custom-conditions#input-variable-validation

Answer (score 3):

An alternative option here that should simplify what you are doing is to set the region and account constraints up so that Terraform will automatically use the correct region and fail if the credentials are not for the correct account.

You can define this in the `aws` provider block. An example might look like this:

```
provider "aws" {
  region              = "eu-west-1"
  allowed_account_ids = ["123456789012"]
}
```

Now if you attempt to use credentials for a different AWS account then Terraform will fail during the plan stage:

```
Error: AWS Account ID not allowed: 234567890123
```

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty useful info! It won't work for the module I'm working on because the "correct" account changes depending on who's using it and a few other factors, but If that weren't the case then this would be a handy solution